# Ordenar DateTimeField apenas por data

Tags: django, classificação

Eu queria ordenar `DateTimeField` apenas por data, ignorando a hora.

Porque na minha ordenação eu preciso de

`Person.objects.order_by('-date_joined', 'full_name')`

Mas a ordenação por nome não surte efeito porque o campo tem hora, mas eu queria só a data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o .extra

```
resultado = Person.objects.extra(select = 
{'date_only': 'to_date(date_joined)'}).order_by('-date_only', 'fullname')
```

Comment: já foi respondido aqui http://stackoverflow.com/a/38151686/802542 Obrigado.